# Exception while creating toolbar

Tags: java, android

When I am going to create the layout which is `toolbar` once it creates 

then it shows this Exception :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils.isLayoutRtl(ViewUtils.java:58)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure_Original(Toolbar.java:1578)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure(Toolbar.java)
>           at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)
>           at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)
>           at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>           at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)
>           at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:590)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:343)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am using Android API 28 and Android Studio version 3.1

My layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary" 
   android:id="@+id/main_app_bar" 
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >     
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When adding information, please [edit] it into the question itself. I have done this for you now. Questions work best if all the information is present in the question itself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
     xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";   
remove semicolom(;) and try again
```

Comment: I have sent a code. if any problem please let me know.Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
use this :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16si7q7T_l4bSlvd5jedrjWHnWzxRE9Ni)

Comment: remove this line android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

Comment: removed still its showing android/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener